# Waits for getting data, Angular & Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

This is the code:

```
      signIn(email, password) {
        let result = true;
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(error => result = false);
        waits(100);
        return result;
      }
```

I've got a service which contains this method above, but return works before getting data from firebase. How I can fix it?

## SOLUTION

login.component.ts

```
  login() {
    this.loggedService.signIn(this.email, this.password).then(value => {
      console.log(value);
      if (value.user !== undefined) {
        this.loggedService.logged = true;
        this.router.navigateByUrl('account');
        console.log(1);
      }
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  }
```

logged.service.ts

```
  signIn(email, password) {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This send a promise:

```
  signIn(email, password) {
      return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
```

And then when you call it do:

```
serviceName.signIn.then({
  //excute your stuff
}).catch({
  // wrong pass or email
});
```

Comment: This doesnt works. I've corrected to
```
  signIn(email, password) {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(succes => true)
      .catch(error => false);
  }

Now the problem is to return.

Comment: I edited it: So what I did here is return the promise in the function. Now in your code you can handle the succes and the error.

Comment: The SignIn will return a promise. Then you where you called this function you can catch it with the `then` for a succes and the `catch` for an error.

Answer (score 0):

As firebase auth returns a `promise` so you can use `await` to wait for request to complete:

```
async signIn(email, password) {
        let result = true;
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(error => result = false);
        return result;
}
```

Comment: But, if i'll put console.log() before return it will work after getting data. Return still works before one.

Answer (score 0):

```
let result = false;

signIn(email, password) {

            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                                    .subcribe( res => {if(res) result = true})
                                    .catch(error => result = false);
          }
```

Comment: "property subscribe does not exist on type 'Promise<UserCredential>'"

Comment: if subcribe does not exist try .then()